# Prism with wp7 and wpf

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, prism, extension-methods

I have a class in my C# class library. I want to add it as a link to my wp7 class library. The only issue is that a wp7 doesn't have the List.RemoveAll(condition) extension method, so I have to use the Prism's List.RemoveAll(condition) for it. But Prism does have this method only for a wp7 but not for a wpf. I don't want to maintain two separate classes only for an one-string difference reason. Is it possible to solve this problem not by rewriting my RemoveAll block in the way it would be wp7-friendly?

Comment: You could just add RemoveAll extension method to your project

Comment: @gabba, Thanks, it'll solve this particular case. But I hoped for a bit more general solution as wp7 lacks a lot more that just the removeall.